# Expandable submenu with sub-sub-menu

Tags: jquery, css

So I am trying to create a simple sidebar using nested list elements that are 3 levels deep, so there's a menu, sub-menu, and sub-sub-menu. Everything seems to function as expected, the only problem is, when I'm in the deepest level list element (sub-sub-menu), and I select an option, my jquery events conflict somehow, and it collapses the menu, unintentionally. I tried using class-specific selectors to prevent this problem with no success. I would like the click on a sub-sub-menu to **not** collapse the parent list.

Also, when a sub-menu is open with sub-sub-menu options and a user selects different sub-menu option (hiding the current sub-menu), then goes back to the initial one that was just collapsed, the sub-sub-menu options are still showing, when they should be hidden.

JQuery

```
$('.docs-index-li-ul').hide();
$('.doc-index-li > a').click(function(){
    $('.docs-index-li-ul').hide();
    $(this).next('ul').show();
});
$('.doc-index-li .docs-index-li-ul li ul li').hide();
$('.docs-index-li-ul li > a').click(function(){
    $('.docs-index-li-ul li ul li').hide();
    $(this).next('ul').children('li').show();
});
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q7vay/

I appreciate any suggestions on why this is happening and how to fix it.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've done two things:

```
$('.docs-index-li-ul > li > a').click(function(){
```

Added a child selector here so that you only get immediate `li`s reacting. Then added:

```
$('.doc-index-li .docs-index-li-ul li ul li a').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

To stop propagation when those sub-sub-menu anchors are clicked:

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/q7vay/1/)

Comment: +1, thank you! It is much better, and very close. However, note, when you click on `food`, then click on `pizza` to show sub-sub-menu, then you click on `cars` so the `food` sub-menu collapses, and the cars are displayed, as it should be. There's a problem, when you click on `food` again, the sub-sub-menu options are still showing on click, when it shouldn't (basically, both sub-menus and sub-sub-menus should be hidden on collapse, not just sub-menu's).